# как поймать пустую строку между двумя \n\n

Tags: c, строки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *token = NULL;

    char string1[] = "first Line\n\nthird line\nOne more line";

    token = strtok(string1, "\n");

    while (token != NULL) {
      size_t line = strlen(token);
      printf("Empty line%s\n", token);
      token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: как распознать строку два, которая является пустой, между

first Line **\n\n** third line\n.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию [strsep](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=strsep&category=3).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *token;

    char string1[] = "first Line\n\nthird line\nOne more line";
    char buf[100];
    sprintf(buf, "%s", string1);
    char *end = buf;
    while ((token = strsep(&end, "\n")) != NULL) {
        if (token[0] == '\0') {
            printf("Empty token\n");
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", token);
        }
      token = end;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Она не определена в стандарте, поэтому, если её на вашей платформе нет, можно воспользоваться [такой](https://unixpapa.com/incnote/string.html) реализацией:

```
#ifndef HAVE_STRSEP
char * strsep(char **sp, char *sep)
{
    char *p, *s;
    if (sp == NULL || *sp == NULL || **sp == '\0') return(NULL);
    s = *sp;
    p = s + strcspn(s, sep);
    if (*p != '\0') *p++ = '\0';
    *sp = p;
    return(s);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Теперь ничего не выводит.

Comment: Да, strtok, судя по всему, пропускает подряд идущие разделители, сейчас напишу, как можно сделать

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Comment: А что такое _strcspn()_? Оно определено в стандарте?

Comment: @0andriy, нет, не определено, это указано в статье, на которую я ссылаюсь. Но strcspn есть в POSIX и ISO.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться стандартной функцией [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string1[] = "first Line\n\nthird line\nOne more line";
    char const sep = '\n';
    char * psz = string1;
    for (;;)
    {
        char * const token = strchr(psz, sep);
        if (token)
        {
            *token = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", psz);
            *token = sep;
            psz = token;
            ++psz;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\n", psz);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/jdzfJ3)